# How can i improve the quality of my baking?

Tags: mesh, uv, baking

This is my low poly hand

[image]

and this is my high poly hand

[image]

I bake the high poly onto the low poly with uv SAMRT PROJECT and this is the result

[image]

Now this is very bad i think . . . i would like to understand if this bad results depends on

- it's my low poly too bad? Maybe should be more similar to the shape of high     poly?
- it's my normal map? Maybe with the unwrap and mark seam could be better? 
  This is my normal map
  [image]
- it's my a problem of settings? 
  For the bake i used this one
  [image]

**EDIT**

After UV SMART PROJECT and BAKING i did these steps:

I add new material and i don't change anything here so settings are

[image]

then i go in texture i click on new texture and then i add the image of the baking like that with these settings.

[image]

In the end in order to see the render i go on object mode - shading - GLSL then i use Ctrl + z

Comment: What is the size of your image that you are baking to? I think you should try doubling this, and try baking again. (eg. 800x600 > 1600x1200).

Comment: What are the settings of normal map assigning to the model ?

Comment: Im using 1024 * 1024 @Rick Riggs

Comment: Mr Zac you wanna know the settings of PNG normal map file?

Comment: I personally would lean toward focusing on my UV map & Seams (Which I think you already feel is the right answer). One variation to this though from my humble opinion, is that I would try to take it limb by limb, in terms of creating & mapping separate objects (also split front and back - You don't have to physically separate you can use vert groups). This would allow you to do most of your work through visual alignment in the viewport, then project from view. The reason for also splitting the limb front and back, would be so you don't project the top of your hand to the palm, etc...

Comment: Mr Zak I edit the question! I hope it's  clear and what you asked me

Comment: Yes now it is. The one problem which I can see is with mesh - its topology. It's not good in several areas, e.g. between fingers, between big finger and arm, probably not everything is visible. There are non-planar faces, ngons etc, which will lead to bad shading of mesh. Another thing - to increase amount of normal map effect increase *Bias* a bit

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! If i could ask you the last thing, how much should i increase Bias? From 0.001 to?
I know there isn't the perfect value but i really don't know how could works the change. Thank you again i really appreciate your effort!!